# Infer type to generics from function's return type

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a storyboard and view controllers in it. Storyboard Id of every view controllers is same as the class name assigned to it. like: a walkthrough view controller is assigned WalkThroughVC class and its storyboard Id is also WalkThroughVC.

I made a function below, to get instance of view controller from storyboard:

```
func getViewController<T: UIViewController>() -> T? {
     let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewController.rawValue) as? T
}
```

Is it possible to infer the type of T? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I think is what you looking for.

```
class ViewControllers
{
    class func getViewController<T : UIViewController>(fromStoryboard : String, fromClass : T) -> T?
    {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: fromStoryboard, bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(fromClass)") as? T
        return controller
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution didn't work "\(fromClass)" wont give the classname instead use of "\(fromClass.classForCoder)" gives class name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 func getViewController<T: UIViewController>() -> T? {
        var fullName: String = NSStringFromClass(T.self)
        let range = fullName.rangeOfString(".", options: .BackwardsSearch)
        if let range = range {
             fullName = fullName.substringFromIndex(range.endIndex)
        }
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        return sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(fullName) as? T

    }
```

Comment: can you give example how can we use this function? Infering type to the T

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't infer in that way. No solution yet,
I used following alternative:

```
func getViewController<T: UIViewController>(ofType: T.Type) -> T? {
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(ofType)") as? T
}
```

and I used it as:

```
let viewController = getViewController(WalkThroughVC)
```